# Website performance gone down after cloudflare cdn activated

Tags: seo, cdn, cloudflare, optimization

I wanted to checkout Cloudflare CDN free version for old website  and activate CDN for it and noticed that website performance was hit after activating CDN. What could be reason as I am new to Cloudflare CDN. Our website is an old website and hosted in dedicated server.

here is my screenshot of GTMetrix :

[image]

CDN was activated yesterday and you can see test run on GTMetrix 15 days back show website much faster than what its is showing since yesterday..

Any advice what could have gone wrong?

Comment: What is the website name?   Have you looked at where the latency is coming in? For example using Chrome -> More Settings -> Developer Tools -< Network

Comment: @davidgo, I just wanted to know  what could be the the top level reasons... as cloudflare should server static contents from cDN server etc..

Comment: First things I'd look at are DNS related issues, then constrained bandwitdth between cloudflare and the server.  After that I'd look into the weeds at things like MTU, threading  issues if thats where the evidence leads.

Comment: One gotcha can be that html files are not cached by default. This means a CDN can negatively effect TTFB as the html has to go from the original servier via the CDN to the user, and not direct.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath, I'm assuming you mean that the html has to go through the CDN for the initial request before it's cached?

Comment: Not exactly. The CDN I use does not cache html pages by default. This is because it cannot assume html files are static. Which means every html request has to come from the original server and go via the CDN.

Comment: I've never used Cloudflare without also having Varnish on my own server. But this is odd. David seems confident here.

Comment: Also see - https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25777/why-is-my-site-slower-with-amazons-cdn